# Swift: "float is not convertible to int"

Tags: swift

How can I convert this to Int? I've tried using the initializer: Int(), using the round method.. All of them generates an error. In this case the one I get is: "float is not convertible to int"

```
  let CirclePoints = 84
  let PI = 3.14159

  let radius: Double!
  let xBase: Int!
  let yBase: Int!
  var xPos = Int()
  var yPos = Int()

  xPos = round(xBase + radius * cos((PI / 10) * circlePoint))
```

Comment: where are your variables (xBase, radius etc) defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend converting all of your values to double since that is what the round function takes. The round function also returns a double, so you'll have to convert the result of round() into an Int to store it in xPos.

```
xPos = Int(round(Double(xBase) + Double(radius) * cos((PI / 10) * Double(circlePoint))))
```

Note that the conversion process here is actually creating new double values from the variables, not changing those variables.